# What is the best if statement to use with 5 variables?

Tags: java, if-statement

So I'm making a yathzee game and I need to check the dices if I've got pairs ones twos and so on. I know that I just can make it with a ton of if statements but waht is the best way of doing it? I've got 5 dices to check for pairs, three of a kind, four of a kind, pair and three of a kind, 12345, 23456, ones, twos threes, fours, fives, sixes and so on.
This would basicly take 5 if statements or more per check.
So I wonder if there is any better way?

I've got the variables dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5

Comment: First thing to do: use an array or a list to handle the 5 values, rather than 5 separate variables...

Comment: Take a more OOP approach to your code.

Comment: I was going to recommend coding a strategy for each possible outcome, and placing all of the strategies into a responsibility chain, with the highest point total first and the lowest last.  But then they closed the question.  :(

Comment: I think the reason this has been put on hold is that you did not show any of your code. Please post some code as a starting point, no matter how sub-optimal it may look to you. Even a small demonstration of genuine effort does wonders on Stack Overflow. Good luck!

Comment: Adding to @JonSkeet, it'll probably nice in your search for pairs, triples, etc. if the array or list were sorted. To recognize a pair and a triple you could say something like `d[0]==d[1] && d[1]!=d[2] && d[2] == d[3] && d[3] == d[4]`